# Roblox Studio: Hinge rotating instead of the door

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make an animated opening/closing door in Roblox Studio. The script works but it's rotating the hinge instead of the door. Please tell me what I did wrong, how would I fix this?

```
local tween = game:GetService("TweenService")

local Center = script.Parent.Center
local Door = "Closed"

local CF = Instance.new("CFrameValue")
CF.Value = Center.CFrame
CF.Changed:Connect(function()
    Center.CFrame = CF.Value
end)

script.Parent.Door.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if Door == "closed" then
        tween:Create(CF, TweenInfo.new(1), {Value = Center .CFrame * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0),math.rad(90),math.rad(0))}):play()
        Door = "open"
    else
    tween:Create(CF, TweenInfo.new(1), {Value = Center .CFrame * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0),math.rad(-90),math.rad(0))}):play()
        Door = "closed"
    end
end)
```

Comment: The official Roblox Developer forums may give you more luck in an answer, however sometimes getting accepted takes a lot of reading to do.

Comment: There are a few errors that may be contributing, such as creating a CFrameValue and parenting to your parts. Firstly, all parts already have a CFrame value, so many lines are not needed. Also, the compiler may not interpret white space, but `Center .CFrame` is poor formatting. Putting the goal and TweenInfo into separate variables will help us to read it better, and for you to debug easier.